# How can i change the language that says in phpMyAdmin in WAMP?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, wamp

I am using:

```
WampServer : 2.5 - 32
Apache     : 2.4.9
MySQL      : 5.6.17
PHP        : 5.5.12
PHPMyAdmin : 4.1.14
SqlBuddy   : 1.3.3
XDebug     : 2.2.5
```

My phpMyAdmin is already in English but when i had an error. It says in a different language.

```
"MySQL said: Documentation
#1146 - La table 'sample.user' n'existe pas"
```

Can anyone help me out? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do 
just as I did...

You have to change in the my.ini file

In the my.ini file, find this line:

```
# Change your locale here !
lc-messages=fr_FR
```

and change it in your desire language:

```
lc-messages=en_GB
```

I changed it here in United Kingdom English

may this help you.... :)

Comment: By the way where can i find the my.ini file?

Comment: or en_US for US locale.

Answer (score 0):

Type My.ini in the search box on that particular Wampp folder.It returns the result from that you can find the My.ini file.